Problems with logic of how to create users with different type of data with jwt in springboot api
I have a table called users, which already has the jwt token logic and all of that, the table has username, password, email and status (so that I can see if the user is active or not instead of straight up deleting it from the db). That table works for one type of user, but I have more than one, so I have another table called admins which only adds the company they work for, I have a veterinary one that adds more data, and a client one which adds different data.
Basically the 3 tables extend from users, but I don't understand how I can make it so that the login for say, the client, fills up the data in user, and generates the jwt token and also fills up the data in the client table in the db
this is my code for the user login:
package com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.Auth;

import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.user.role;
import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.user.user;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.Jwt.jwtService;
import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.user.userRepository;
import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.Config.ApplicationConfig;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.repositories.IAdminRepository;
import javax.management.relation.Role;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class authService {

    private final userRepository userRepository;
    private final jwtService jwtService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final IAdminRepository adminRepository;

    public authResponse login (loginRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getContraseña()));
        UserDetails userDetails = userRepository.findByUsername(request.getUsername()).orElseThrow();
        String token = jwtService.getToken(userDetails);
        return authResponse.builder()
                .token(token)
                .build();
    }
    //Register admindios
    public authResponse register (registerRequest request) {
        user user1 = user.builder()
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .username(request.getUsername())
                .contrasena(passwordEncoder.encode( request.getContraseña()))
                .role(role.ADMINDIOS)
                .build();

        userRepository.save(user1);

        return authResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtService.getToken(user1))
                .build();
    }

}

that's the service
I tried doing basically the same thing from the user only login but I don't know how to make it do both the user login and jwt generation process and the database save of the other info
this is the user model
package com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.user;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "user")
public class user implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "contraseña")
    private String contrasena;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "estatus")
    private String estatus;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    role role;


this is the client model
package com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.models;

import com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.user.user;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class clientModel extends user {

    @Column(name = "nombre_usuario")
    private String nombreUsuario;
    @Column(name = "numero_contacto")
    private String numeroContacto;
    @Column(name = "foto_perfil")
    private String fotoPerfil;
    @Column(name = "id_sucursal")
    private int idSucursal;

this is the user repository, the client one is basically the same thing
package com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<user, Integer> {
    Optional<user> findByUsername(String username);
}

this is the user register request
package com.ApiRestfulBackendVet.ApiRestfulBackendVet.Auth;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class registerRequest {
    String email;
    String username;
    String contraseña;
    String estatus;
}


It would help us a lot if you followed the usual Java coding conventions and named all the classes starting with an uppercase letter. Also please add code for your entities and repositories.

Sorry for the classes thing, its my first time using springboot, i already added the entities related to what i need, hope you can help, im very confused because its the first time i use jwt and i dont understand how i can create a user and add it to the user table and make his token while also adding other data to another entity at the same time, i also have more type of users, with different entities but i can work through it with just one example, sorry for bothering
